# Amazon Alexa custom skill issue in ios app

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to implement custom skills using Amazon Alexa Skill Kit (ASK). I have configured Amazon Alexa Voice Service (AVS) and ASK project, Then created lambda function also.

I have 2 custom intents.

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "fIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "bIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a Utterances like below

- fIntent get info
- fIntent get status
- fIntent find info
- fIntent info

Here is my index.js code

```
'use strict';
var Alexa       = require('alexa-sdk');
var SKILL_NAME  = 'ScottSkill';
var APP_ID      = '';


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};


var handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit(':tellWithCard','Hi, Im your personal car assistant. How can i help you');
    },
    'fIntent':function (){
        this.emit(':tell','Fuel level is 100');
    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        var readFuel        = 'Iam Personal car assistant, I can assist you with car info';
        var speeachOutput   = readFuel;
        var reprompt        = 'How can I help you';
        this.emit(':ask', speeachOutput, reprompt);
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', 'OKay, Goodbye');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', 'OKay, Goodbye');
    }
};
```

Now the problem is when I'm saying skill name I'm getting *LaunchRequest* message. 
But when I'm trying to get custom intent value by saying  **fIntent info** 
I'm not getting the message what I configured in the index.js file.

if I say **info** its should tell **Fuel level is 100**.

But I'm Not getting that info. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please test using the Service Simulator and share the log details

Comment: I understood the problem is event request and directive response json issue.

Comment: can u help me with that

Comment: Sure, I will check the same

Comment: I need proper json request for event and directive

Comment: I don't have a problem with skill or above code. I need the json request for events and directives.

Comment: I got the solution,, Thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

Don't develop the two components at one.

First develop you skill and test it from an Echo device

Once you are done, develop your Amazon Voice Service app

Comment: Something linking in missing some where. I m getting response "Sorry i don't know that" for my custom skill

Comment: I got the solution,, Thanks for all